# Qt5 audio oscillogram

Tags: c++, qt, audio, video, qt5

I need to draw an oscillogram of audio track. The audio could be stored with video too. I play audio with such code:

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;
//connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), this, SLOT(positionChanged(qint64)));
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/mikhail/Downloads/BRAT.mkv"));
player->play();
```

I need to play any of audio tracks in video file and display it's oscillogram.

How can I realize it?

I've found an example in Qt examples: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-audio-example.html . That's what I need but the sound streams from micro. I'm new at Qt, although an example is simple, I can't understand how to replace data from micro with data from player.

I can guess that I need to replace QAudioInput:

```
QAudioFormat formatAudio;
formatAudio.setSampleRate(8000);
formatAudio.setChannelCount(1);
formatAudio.setSampleSize(8);
formatAudio.setCodec("audio/pcm");
formatAudio.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
formatAudio.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

QAudioDeviceInfo inputDevices = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
m_audioInput = new QAudioInput(inputDevices,formatAudio, this);

m_device = new XYSeriesIODevice(m_series, this);
m_device->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

m_audioInput->start(m_device);
```

But I can't find how to give to QAudioInput a buffer of raw data from QMediaPlayer.

Also I have working code to get raw data with ffmpeg, but I think it could be done with QMediaPlayer and it would be easier.

Thanks for any help!